# How to analyse reaction times in SPSS?

Tags: anova, t-test, spss

I've learnt basic stats but I'm a bit confused on how I should so this, I'm gonna try and explain it as best as I could.

So I had participants doing a driving simulation which includes two different alerts inserted at different times throughout, and I have 3 different programs to counterbalance the order of the alerts.

So my reaction time looks like this in the end:

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNhTv.png)

Each row is a different participant doing a different order of alerts, and the transparent vs highlighted indicates two different alert.

1. So how do I find out whether the highlighted RT is significantly shorter than the transparent one?
2. How should I organise my data in SPSS since the alerts are in different order ...?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the order thing but I would organize the data in long format so that there would be 3 rows per participant, each corresponding to one reaction time, then one variable indicating which alert was used and one variable indicating in which "order program" the participant was in (this variable would have only one value per participant).

Answer (score 0):

To continue my comment, if there are two alert types (that vary within participants) and 3 possible orders (that do not vary within, only between participants), and 3 reaction time measurements per participant, I would organize the data like this:

```
   id_nro alert_type order        RT
       1          2     1 4.6689560
       1          1     1 3.7079620
       1          2     1 1.3768914
       2          1     2 2.0971152
       2          1     2 2.0333446
       2          2     2 3.2799651
       3          2     3 2.4166309
       3          1     3 2.7533185
       3          1     3 2.4714532
       4          2     1 2.4571295
...
#this is generated example data so ignore the weird "reaction times"
```

And I'd analyze the data with a multilevel model (e.g. linear mixed model) with alert type (as categorical/factor predictor) predicting reaction time and including the random intercept of participant (to deal with repeated measures) and the fixed effect of order (to control for order).